# Decode BLOB in SQLite file

Tags: database, sqlite, blob, decode

I am relatively new to SQLite but I've been trying to do some research and browse a database file that I am trying to extract data from.

In one table in particular, the data from most of the columns is easily readable, but one column has BLOB data which I cannot read. I was able to export this table to CSV and HTML but the BLOB data looks something like:

Â­Â“]oÃ› Â†Ã¿ Ã¢ÂžÃ–pÂŒÃ§Â¢Â•ÂºeÂšÂ´IÂÂ´Ã«>,(Â®

I was wondering if there is any way to decode this unreadable data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The purpose of BLOBs is to contain non-textual data.

Comment: So there must be a way then to decode it in such a way that it is represented by its GIFs or JPGs or whatever format they are encoded in?

Comment: Yes, if you know what the format is.